# I want to change MySQL database folder to new location but got error

Tags: mysql

I tried many times to change MySQL Database default folder to my new folder but got following error, Please anybody help to fix this.

"Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and"journalctl -xe"for details."

I am using Ubuntu 20.04

Thank you!

Comment: Please elaborate, which command did you use ? You could also insert output for the "journalctl -xe" command

Comment: Hi John,
I tried exactly same as the following method
https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-relocate-a-mysql-data-directory-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: The try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795176/how-to-change-mysql-data-directory